# Logrotate permission errors when using compress

Tags: logrotate

I'm struggling to make logrotate work. Basically I just want to have a cronjob run once an hour to rotate my logs.

Now I had this working initially but logrotate completely crapped itself and stopped working after only changing a filename, being the wonderful software that it is...

Now I'm running into incomprehensible permission errors when running `logrotate --force myconfig` with compress. If I comment out compress the log gets rotated and 12345678.log-2021010608 is created without errors.

I have no idea why this is happening. Permissions look OK to me and I have tried using the `su` and `create` options. I also tried running the command as root but than it just does... nothing. No errors or files are created.

error:

```
error: error setting owner of /home/user/test/12345678.log-2021010608.gz to uid 1000 and gid 1001: Operation not permitted
```

permissions:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 user group   70 Jan  6 08:02 12345678.log
-rw-r--r--  1 user group   140 Jan  6 08:00 12345678.log-2021010608
-rw-------  1 user user    0 Jan  6 08:01 12345678.log-2021010608.gz
```

Logrotate conf:

```
/home/user/test/*.log {
#        su user group
        hourly
        dateext
        dateformat -%Y%m%d%H
        missingok
        compress
#        compressoptions -9
#        create 644 user group
        rotate 2
        notifempty
        nocreate
        postrotate
               sudo systemctl restart serial.service
        endscript
}
```

For testing I also chmod 777 the folder and the .log file but that made no difference.

Comment: "operation not permitted" indicates that either *logrotate* or *gzip* try to change ownership of the gzip file (`chown(2)` system call). Only the superuser is allowed to do this. It's not quite clear to me, however, why ownership must be changed, and how that can be avoided.

Comment: What type of filesystem stores this directory?

Comment: Whatever ubuntu 18 server installs with by default. I think that is ext4?

As the logs rotate using --force I added that to my crontab. Its not pretty and I would like to know why its required but for now at least my logs are rotated.